# The property context on type ProjectName.Repositories.MyRepo is not settable?

Tags: design-patterns, dependency-injection, asp.net-mvc-5, repository, unity-container

I am creating a mvc project to learn Repository pattern. i am using DBFirst approach + Entity Framework + Unity for DI. I am following this article:

https://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet-mvc/1155/aspnet-mvc-repository-pattern-perform-database-operations

I have followed this article and it's working fine. But after it I

> created a new table in database Teacher and update the database
>
> Later I add TeacherInfoRepository, In unityconfig file registered the TeacherInfoRepository
>
> Add controller and then add view

I performed above steps as it is defined in the article I mentioned above.
But after I tried running /Teachers/Index view It gives the error:

```
The property context on type ProjectName.Repositories.TeacherInfoRepository is not settable.
```

I searched on google but unfortunately didn't find something like this.

Please guide me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I check the example you provided on the link, and also the source code on GitHub, but it seems that in your unity configuration is lacking the injection  of the context property you have declared.

That means that on the file UnityConfig.cs, before this line:

```
container.RegisterType<IRepository<EmployeeInfo,int>,EmployeeInfoRepository>();
```

You should put something like:

```
container.RegisterType<ApplicationEntities>();
```

That will allow that when unity is creating the instance of EmployeeInfoRepository, to instantiate the context which is needed to access the database.